# Amcharts Balloon background color disappears when exporting as image

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, amcharts

I am trying to export an amchart as a PNG or JPG. If I hover the cursor on the amchart before the image gets downloaded the balloon appears in the downloaded image with no background color.

```js
var chartData = [{
  date: '12/5/2018',
  visits: 100
}, {
  date: '12/6/2018',
  visits: 200
}, {
  date: '12/8/2018',
  visits: 170
}, {
  date: '12/10/2018',
  visits: 320
}];

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "theme": "black",
  "type": "serial",
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "valueAxes": [{
    "id": "v1",
    "axisAlpha": 0.1
  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "useNegativeColorIfDown": true,
    "balloonText": "[[category]]<br><b>value: [[value]]</b>",
    "bullet": "round",
    "valueField": "visits"
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "valueLineEnabled": true,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true
  },
  "categoryField": "date",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true,
    "backgroundColor": '#3B3B3C',
  }
});
```

Can someone give me a solution for this issue? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: At first presentation this appears to be a bug - assuming you've followed the documentation. We can't verify that, though, as you've not shown us your code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have attached the sample code

Comment: Thank you. The code looks fine. I would raise this issue with the developers as this definitely appears to be a bug in their logic which creates the images

Comment: Can you create a codepen or some sort of demo that reproduces this? I just checked with [this example](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/position-chart-cursor-show-balloon-exporting-image/) and the axis and graph balloons both export with their respective background color.

Comment: @xorspark that's interesting. I wonder if the OP is using an older version of the library which needs updating.

Comment: @xorspark Please find the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/9zyt6hu1/
This issue differs from the safari browser and chrome browser.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am using amcharts V3.

Comment: @user3062437 I just tested this in Safari 12 and the latest version of Chrome and it shows up correctly for me.